# catastrophic disasters due to software system failures

Tags: fault-tolerance

I know this is not a programming problem, but this problem is related to computer systems I am posting this question.

Can somebody tell me a good place to find out information related to catastrophic disasters due to software system failures? For example incidents like [Therac-25](http://cs-netlab-01.lynchburg.edu/courses/MACFAST/ComputerDisasters/Therac-25/Wikipedia/Therac-25%20-%20Wikipedia,%20the%20free%20encyclopedia.htm).

The [risk digest](http://catless.ncl.ac.uk/risks) is a good place, but information it provides for each case is not enough for my requirement.

Thanks

Comment: why not link to Wikipedia directly?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040338/what-are-the-worst-software-project-failures-ever

Comment: Why would anyone care about boring subjects like this when they can make new shitty programming languages that aren't even on par with what was made in the 70s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of other places that spring to mind if the Risks archive is not sufficient.

One is Robert Glass's book '[Software Runaways: Catastrophic Disasters due to Software System Failures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013673443X)'.

The other is P G Neumann's book based on the Risks archive, '[Computer-Related Risks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020155805X)', which is now a bit dated (1994; wow, time flies!).

---

Glass also has a book '[ComputingFailure.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130917397)' that is apposite.  You might consider '[Death March](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013143635X)' and '[Decline and Fall of the American Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013191958X)' (Yourdon) as related too.

Comment: @Jonathan. Sorry for this bit of "meta" but what are these URLs to Amazon? (rads.stackoverflow.com/...) ? Is this the recommended way to link to this vendor [from SO] ?

Comment: @mjv: I wrote the URLs as Amazon; SO rewrites them so they get the appropriate kick-back from Amazon as people click through.  This was discussed in the SO blog a few months ago, IIRC (and probably in extenso in Meta-SO).

Comment: Thank you for the info, Jonathan. Makes sense [that a) SO would like kick-back and b) that this would be easy transparent for SO contributors].

Comment: @mjv: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/our-amazon-advertising-experiment/